# How do I dismiss the bottom sheet from a button click event inside the bottom sheet?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I used this control in my project:
https://github.com/the49ltd/The49.Maui.BottomSheet

I have created a bottom sheet on my homepage, it can be dismissed when I tapped outside the bottom sheet, but it seems cannot be dismissed once I click a button inside of the bottom sheet.

This is my code to display the bottom sheet:

```cs
private async void OnClicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        sheet.HasHandle = true;
        sheet.IsCancelable = true;
                
        await sheet.ShowAsync(Window);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error!", ex.Message, "OK!");
    }
}
```

This is my XAML code:

```xml
<btm:BottomSheet xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SampleProject.CustomViews.TicketListBottomSheet"
             xmlns:btm = "https://schemas.the49.com/dotnet/2023/maui"
             Padding="16,32"
             Background="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White},Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}"
             >
    <Grid Margin="0,2,0,5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="Cancel" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="Bold"  WidthRequest="150" TextColor="#1414A0" BackgroundColor="#E5E5FF" CornerRadius="20"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Clicked="Cancel_Clicked" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Apply" FontAttributes="Bold"  FontFamily="Bold" WidthRequest="150" Style="{StaticResource PrimaryButtonStyle}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Clicked="Apply_Clicked"/>
    </Grid>
</btm:BottomSheet>
```

I want the bottom sheet to be able to be self dismissed within the control itself once I clicked the 'Cancel' button

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show the code-behind of the bottom sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have check the control link you provided and found that you can call the [sheet.DismissAsync()](https://github.com/the49ltd/The49.Maui.BottomSheet/blob/64a1a6fba1599b060f936307c0b9169c881d0856/src/BottomSheet.cs#L112) to make the bottom sheet disappear. So you can try to use the control's parent property to get the instance of BottomSheet. Such as:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            var control = sender as Button;
            var bottomsheet = control.Parent.Parent as BottomSheet;
          // the first parent is grid and the second parent is BottomSheet
          bottomsheet.DismissAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code-behind of your bottom sheet, put the following code into the Cancel button's event handler to call the `DismissAsync()` method on the bottom sheet to close it:

```cs
private async void Cancel_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await DismissAsync();
}
```